# Run-time error 1004: Unable to set the Name property of PivotItem class

Tags: excel, vba

First time when I execute this function, it works as it should. Second time when I execute with some setting change not related this piece of code I get the Run-Time error 1004

```
    With PT.PivotFields("Group")
        For i = LBound(GroupNames) To UBound(GroupNames)
            .PivotItems(GroupNames(i)).Position = i + 1
        Next i
    End With
```

Here is the function,

```
Public Sub Create_Pivots_Calculation()
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PC As PivotCache
Dim PTRng As Range
Dim WSTemp As Worksheet, WSSummary As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Set PTRng = Range("Rate_Data") 'Pivot table range
Set ECARDataRangeCalc = Range("Range_ECAR_Data") 'Where OCRTable begins to be added
Set WSTemp = Sheets.Add 'The new empty sheet
Set WSSummary = Sheets("Summary Printout") 'The output sheet

Set PC = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PTRng)

With WSTemp
'Create a pivot table with the Rate data.
'we are recreating the data with group and Well as the column and time as the row for calculation.
Set PT = .PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PC, TableDestination:=.Range("A100"))
PT.ErrorString = 0
PT.DisplayErrorString = True

With PT
    .ColumnGrand = False
    .RowGrand = False

    .PivotFields("Group").Orientation = xlColumnField
    .PivotFields("Well").Orientation = xlColumnField
    .PivotFields("Time").Orientation = xlRowField

     PT.AddDataField PT.PivotFields("ECAR"), "Average", xlAverage
    'Hide the Background group
    On Error Resume Next
    .PivotFields("Group").PivotItems("Background").Visible = False
    On Error GoTo 0

 'Use average of ECAR in the data field
 'Sort the pivot as per the selected group order in the GUI

    With PT.PivotFields("Group")
        For i = LBound(GroupNames) To UBound(GroupNames)
            .PivotItems(GroupNames(i)).Position = i + 1
        Next i
    End With

    'Clear the existing range for all data
    WSSummary.Range(ECARDataRangeCalc, ECARDataRangeCalc.Offset(100, 0)).EntireRow.ClearContents
    'Paste the new data in the OCR Data range
    .TableRange1.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rowsize:=.TableRange1.Rows.Count - 1).Copy ECARDataRangeCalc
    ECARDataRangeCalc = "Time (min)"
    Set ECARDataRangeCalc = ECARDataRangeCalc.CurrentRegion 'Reset the OCRDataRange
    Set ECARDataRangesCalc(0) = ECARDataRangeCalc
    'On the basis of OCRDataRange build the OCRDataRange for next summary - this will be after one column where OCRDataRange ends
    Set ECARDataRangeCalc = ECARDataRangeCalc.Offset(0, ECARDataRangeCalc.Columns.Count + 1)

  End With
'Delete the temp sheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End With

Set PC = Nothing
Set PT = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any help appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Does changing the line:

```
Set PT = .PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PC, TableDestination:=.Range("A100"))
```

to

```
Set PT = .PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PC, TableDestination:=WSTemp.Range("A100"))
```

fix the problem for you?

Comment: Nope, still the same issue

Comment: The issue was not in this function... so I resolved it... thank you